# Use data separated by delimiters in Sql Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a Sql Procedure that receives a string as a parameter.
Now the task that I need to perform is that the parameter contains data that is separated by two different kinds of delimiters i.e **":"** and **","**

There are two columns in the DB **Id** and **Value**.

```
     sample Data: "10:0,11:1,12:3,13:4,15:5,16:6"
     In This case          Ids are: 10,11,12,13,14,15,16
     and their respective  values are: 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Now I want to insert these values in DB.
Can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Two different products, with different stored procedures.)

Comment: Depending on your sql client (meaning the code that executes the stored procedure) you might be able to use a table valued parameter for that. It would be the best solution.

Comment: @jarlh I'm guessing sql server since the OP added both sql-server and sql-server-2008 tags

Comment: @ZoharPeled, probably. But when in doubt, ask!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion..
I am using SQL Server 2008..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Split (
      @InputString                  VARCHAR(8000),
      @Delimiter                    VARCHAR(50)
)

RETURNS @Items TABLE (
      Item                          VARCHAR(8000)
)

AS
BEGIN
      IF @Delimiter = ' '
      BEGIN
            SET @Delimiter = ','
            SET @InputString = REPLACE(@InputString, ' ', @Delimiter)
      END

      IF (@Delimiter IS NULL OR @Delimiter = '')
            SET @Delimiter = ','

      DECLARE @Item                 VARCHAR(8000)
      DECLARE @ItemList       VARCHAR(8000)
      DECLARE @DelimIndex     INT

      SET @ItemList = @InputString
      SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
      WHILE (@DelimIndex != 0)
      BEGIN
            SET @Item = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, 0, @DelimIndex)
            INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)

            -- Set @ItemList = @ItemList minus one less item
            SET @ItemList = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, @DelimIndex+1, LEN(@ItemList)-@DelimIndex)
            SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
      END -- End WHILE

      IF @Item IS NOT NULL -- At least one delimiter was encountered in @InputString
      BEGIN
            SET @Item = @ItemList
            INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)
      END

      -- No delimiters were encountered in @InputString, so just return @InputString
      ELSE INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@InputString)

      RETURN

END -- End Function
GO

CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    Item NVARCHAR(1000)
)

INSERT INTO #Test
SELECT * FROM Split('10:0,11:1,12:3,13:4,15:5,16:6', ':')

SELECT f.* FROM #Test t
CROSS APPLY Split(t.Item, ',') f

DROP TABLE #Test
```

Comment: As string splitters go this "nibbler" style is the worst performer. It returns the correct results just a lot slower than a number of other methods. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 2):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Test') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Test
GO

CREATE TABLE #Test(ID INT,Val INT)

DECLARE @t table (val varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @t (val)values ('10:0,11:1,12:3,13:4,15:5,16:6')


;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT   
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
 FROM  (SELECT   
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([val], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  @t) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a))
     INSERT INTO #Test 
     select SUBSTRING(String,0,CHARINDEX(':',String)),REVERSE(SUBSTRING(reverse(String),0,CHARINDEX(':',reverse(String)))) from cte 

     select * from #test
```

Comment: You can replace `REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(String), 0,
                                      CHARINDEX(':', REVERSE(String))))`  with `RIGHT(@s, LEN(@s) - CHARINDEX(':', @s))`

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for a quick response.. This query is working to quite an extent but I need To add a where clause in the insert query.. Its Like if I have a Key-Value Pair say '10:1, 11:2', I need to too look for value '10' and insert value 1 for the resopective column.
Right Now an extra null row is being inserted and i cant figure out why is that happening.
 Am I making any sense?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Can you please suggest how can I add a where clause in the above query?

Comment: Can anyone suggest how can I add a where clause in the above query.
 
"INSERT INTO #Test 
     select SUBSTRING(String,0,CHARINDEX(':',String)),REVERSE(SUBSTRING(reverse(String),0,CHARINDEX(':',reverse(String)))) from cte" .

 I have to put a where clause on the first item. eg. if the key value pair is "10:1", I have to find the Key in the DB.i.e. I have to look for value "10" in "Key" column and insert the value "1" in "value" column.

@GiorgiNakeuri

Comment: @GauravSachdeva, it is kind of different question. You can create another thread.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff can you suggest something

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri : Here is link to new thread.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30797025/adding-a-where-clause-to-sql-query-using-delimiters

Thakns in advance

Comment: why i have lost my score -15 is that anything wrong i did @GiorgiNakeuri

Comment: @mohan111, why are you asking me about this? Ask op why he changed accepted answer.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri ok now i got it because of changing the answer it happened.i just want to know the reason that's why i have asked you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function for that, it will handle your two delimiters for spli

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MultipleSplitStrings
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Separator1 Varchar(100),
   @Separator2 Varchar(100)
)
RETURNS  TABLE 
AS

   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(REPLACE(@List, ISNULL(@Separator1,''), '</i><i>') , ISNULL(@Separator2,''), '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );

GO  

Select * From dbo.MultipleSplitStrings ('10:0,11:1,12:3,13:4,15:5,16:6',',',':')
```

Result :

```
item 
10
0
11
1
12
3
13
4
15
5
16
6
```