# Adding a where clause to Sql Query using delimiters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have following stored procedure which accepts a string which uses two delimiters. The procedure extracts the data and inserts into DB.  It's Like if I have a Key-Value Pair **(Sample input string)** say '10:1,11:2,12:3', I need to too look for value '10' in **"Id"** column and insert value 1 in the **"value"** column and so on. 
The code for procedure is as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [SQL_Delimiter_TestProcedure]
@inputStr VARCHAR(MAX) 
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @t table (val varchar(500))

INSERT INTO @t (val)values (@inputStr)


;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT   
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(500)') AS String  
 FROM  (SELECT   
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([val], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  @t) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a))
     INSERT INTO SQL_Delimiter_Test 
     select SUBSTRING(String,0,CHARINDEX(':',String)),REVERSE(SUBSTRING(reverse(String),0,CHARINDEX(':',reverse(String))))  from cte 

END
```

Comment: Why not use a table-valued parameter? Those are *designed* for passing structured data with multiple values in multiple columns. As opposed to a string. Which isn't.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : Can you please suggest how can I implemnt such a query or give a sample may be. I am new to using delimiters and hence do not have much idea.

Comment: Another opportunity for me to post a link to Erland Sommarskog's [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html)

Comment: [MSDN on Table-Valued Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) - the idea is that you *don't* use delimiters - there are types *designed* for holding multiple values, and you use one of those instead.

Comment: Can't use table valued.. Need to stick with delimiters only. The procedure mentioned above does the job but the only thing missing is a where clause. Isn't there any way we can update the existing procedure itself?
@Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: Why can't you use table valued parameters? from what code are you exeuting this stored procedure?

Comment: Will be passing parameters to a WCF service from jQuery.

Comment: You can parse the delimited string and create a datatable inside the wcf service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the short version:

First, Create a user defined table type:

```
CREATE TYPE KeyValuePair As Table
(
    Key int PRIMARY KEY,
    Value int
)
```

Then use it as a table valued parameter in your stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [SQL_Delimiter_TestProcedure]
(
   @KeyValuePair as KeyValuePair readonly
)
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO SQL_Delimiter_Test (Id, Value)
SELECT Key, Value
FROM @KeyValuePair

END
```

More information can be found on [the link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) provided by [Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever) in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar which I shortly adapted for you. I used a udf for that. But you can extract the needed code and easily implement it in your procedure.

In the example I generate the udf and use it to split the value pairs. Afterwards I substring everything to split the key and the value.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_split (@String nvarchar(max), @Delimiter nchar(1))

RETURNS @Results Table (Items nvarchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Index int
    DECLARE @Slice nvarchar(max)

    SET @Index = 1

    IF @String IS NULL RETURN

    WHILE @Index != 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Index = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String)

        IF @Index != 0
            SELECT @Slice = LEFT(@String, @Index - 1)
        ELSE
            SELECT @Slice = @String

            INSERT INTO @Results(Items) VALUES (LTRIM(RTRIM(@Slice)))
                SELECT @String = RIGHT(@String, LEN(@String) - @Index)

            IF Len(@String) = 0 BREAK
        END
    RETURN
END
GO

SELECT SUBSTRING(split.Items,1,PATINDEX(N'%:%',split.items)-1), SUBSTRING(split.Items,PATINDEX(N'%:%',split.items)+1,LEN(split.items))
FROM dbo.udf_split('10:1,11:2,12:3',N',') as split
```